Is it possible to highlight lowest and highest numbers in filtered cells?
I want to highlight the lowest or highest numbers in column D and E in below example but I want it to be done automatically after I filter out different models on column A. Is it possible?


Quick way to color cells in a range
Select cells
(e.g. type 1, 2, 3, ..., 9 in cells, then select them)
Then do: Menu > Format > Conditional > Color scale
maximum and minimum VISIBLE value in e.g. AutoFilter
... set a style for each.
=subtotal(104,D:D)   # max
=subtotal(105,D:D)   # min
Now use these in setting up conditional formatting.
Click e.g. the D column header (i.e. select the column)
Menu: Format >Conditional > Condition > Equals
A dialog pops up.
Range is set to D1:D1048576 (as you selected the column)
Type =subtotal(104,D:D) in the upper box,
select the style to apply
Click OK.
Do the same one more time and use the formula for MIN above. Select another Style for this one though.
Ref: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/SUBTOTAL
LibreOffice 24.2.4.2

This is not what I'm asking.

New way... maybe the right one.

It is highlighting the empty cells now.

That is strange then, I tested this and had it working at that moment. Clean out any other attempted settings for this?

Quick Check; "works for me!"

1-9 numbers twice on rows, Autofilter (Shift+Ctrl+L) and deselecting 1, 8 and 9 from the inverted-triangle-menu -» 2:s and 8:s highlighted.

I tried again removing the formula and copying the numbers created by formula over the cells. Now it's working but I need that formula to obtain dates.

Dates are actually numbers internally in spreadsheets; a day count from a base date (Type a 0 in a cell and set it to be a date, this will reveal the base date). so "max(set of dates)" equals the latest date. The TOD is stored in the fraction.

TOD: 1 hour is 1/24:th of a day, 0.041666667 numerically

Normally I copy dates from an outside source in this format: "10.2012-12.2018". Then I use a formula to remove the months and leave the years alone. I try to apply conditional formatting to the years but it doesn't work.

It is often "good" (easiest) to enter a simulated "full" date, e.g. 2018-12-01 and then format the cell to display whatever  you wish by CTRL-1 (format cell).

It is not in my hand. I copy the dates from an outside source.

And by that you have control over them, write a macro, or even a short python script.

For example, to highlight the highest values in column D, go to Format > Conditional > Manage.

Formula Is D1=MAX(D:D)
Apply Style Good

Result:


It doesn't work. First of all I have to enter a range. Even if I enter a range, I don't see any highlighted value. Is it because I want to do it on cells that contain formulas?

Maybe the formulas are creating strings instead of numbers? Please edit the question and give steps to reproduce a simplified example that demonstrates the problem. As you can see in my screenshot, it works if the setup is correct.

No, the formula is creating numbers. If I remove the formula and copy the numbers it works.
